# How do I retrieve the details of the Checks & Payments screen using the REST API?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use Postman to retrieve the details of the Checks & Payments via the REST API.  I'm using the 'Check' endpoint, which lists the 'Details', but they all have a warning icon on the detail fields:

[image]

If I try to retrieve using this:

```
...22.200.001/Check?$expand=Details
```

I get this error message mess:

[image]

I have no idea what any of that means.  I've used $expand=Details on other endpoints and it works find.  What's wrong here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong actually. That warning message means you can get the Details section only if you are accessing 1 record either by keys or by ID.
The below request should work fine and return the Details section if there is anything

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://ACUMATICA_URL/entity/Default/20.200.001/Check/Payment/CHECK_NUMBER?$expand=Details'
```

but this request will fail as it tries to get a list of records (even with limit=1 it is still a list) and not a single specific check

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://ACUMATICA_URL/entity/Default/20.200.001/Check/Payment/?$expand=Details&$limit=1'
```

Comment: I used:  entity/Default/22.200.001/Check/000001?$expand=Details.  Also tried: entity/Default/22.200.001/Check/'000001'?$expand=Details.   Same error:  "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Comment: I also tried: entity/Default/22.200.001/Check?ReferenceNbr eq '000001'&$expand=Details.   That gave me the error I originally showed above...

Comment: @pmfith it should be `entity/Default/22.200.001/Check/Payment/000001?$expand=Details` you need to provide both keys - Document Type and Reference number

Comment: ok- I realize now that, since this is a Check type, I need:  ...entity/Default/22.200.001/Check/Check/000001?$expand=Details (not Check/Payment/000001...)  Thanks much.. ;D

Comment: @pmfith in the latest 23R1 preview they renamed the Check type to Payment, that's why I had /Check/Payment, but yes in all the previous versions you will have to have /Check/Check